# Python list as function argument

Tags: python, list

My goal is to try to return all the value in the list which has even position as well. The following is my python code. I don't know which part should I update. Please help!! Thanks

```
def evenValue(numbers):
    results = []
    for x in numbers:
        if results.index(x) %2 ==0:
            results.append(x)
    return results
```

My error message is

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    evenValue([1,2,3,4,5,6])
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 4, in evenValue
    if results.index(x) %2 ==0:
ValueError: 1 is not in list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def evenValue(numbers):
    results = []
    for x in numbers:
        if numbers.index(x) %2 ==0:   #Use 'numbers' list instead of 'results' list
            results.append(x)
    return results
print(evenValue([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

**Output**:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this. The slice takes even numbered elements.

```
def evenValue(numbers):
    return numbers[0::2]
```

or shorter:

```
evenValue=lambda numbers: numbers[0::2]
```

Comment: Clever use of heuristics to find even indexes in a sequence: take every other element... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
lst = list(range(50))
even_indexes = lambda numbers: [lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if i%2==0]
even_indexes(lst)
```